# How iterate xml-nodes with Groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

Started work with SoapUI and can't  catch idea how to treat Soap responses with Groovy.
Currently my project opened in NetBeans and after debuging will be copy-pasted to the SoapUI (eviware)
My question is:

```
def Input = """ <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <S:Body>
      <ns2:getSalesAuditsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://apidto.dto.t2.wsapi.ng.com/">
         <return>
            <code>0909019000004830</code>
            <realOpenAmount>12</realOpenAmount>
            <dueDate>2009-07-11T00:00:00+03:00</dueDate>
         </return>
         <return>
            <code>0909119000006260</code>
            <realOpenAmount>55.75</realOpenAmount>
            <dueDate>2007-02-11T00:00:00+02:00</dueDate>
         </return>
      </ns2:getSalesAuditsResponse>    </S:Body> </S:Envelope>
    """
```

How to find "return" Node with specific dueDate ?
As I can assume, it can be near next:

```
def document = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText(Input);
def sa = document.depthFirst().findAll { it.@dueDate=="2007-02-01T00:00:00+02:00" }
```

But sa is [] at this case.
And after all how to delete found node in original XML ?

I'am trying with XMLHolder, but did not know how to initialize it in Netbeans "context" variable which does existed within SoapUI.

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(???context???)
def dataHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( Input )
def data = dataHolder.getDomNode("//return[dueDate="2007-02-11T00:00:00+02:00"]")

And last more general question:
Is it possible to debug groovy scripts in NetBeans and use it later in SoapUI 3.0.1 ?
Or it is impossible to get code autocomplete and doc on demand for groovy_for_SoapUI ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

it.@dueDate is referencing a "dueDate" attribute, not node.  Second, you're looking for "2007-02-01..." in your code, which should have been "2007-02-11..." to match an actual node in your input XML, I'd guess.

So, this does work:

```
def Input = """ <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <S:Body>
        <ns2:getSalesAuditsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://apidto.dto.t2.wsapi.ng.com/">
           <return>
              <code>0909019000004830</code>
              <realOpenAmount>12</realOpenAmount>
              <dueDate>2009-07-11T00:00:00+03:00</dueDate>
           </return>
           <return>
              <code>0909119000006260</code>
              <realOpenAmount>55.75</realOpenAmount>
              <dueDate>2007-02-11T00:00:00+02:00</dueDate>
           </return>
       </ns2:getSalesAuditsResponse>
     </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
    """
def document = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText(Input);
def sa = document.depthFirst().findAll {it.dueDate == "2007-02-11T00:00:00+02:00"}
```

If I intended to modify the XML, I think I'd end up using the standard MarkupBuilder or StreamingMarkupBuilder to output new XML in the form I wanted.